# Como debo enviar datos por FETCH como condiciones para mi WHERE en mi consulta SELECT SQL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

tengo un request FETCH donde necesito enviar datos para que mi API EXPRESS los reciba y vaya directo al WHERE de mi SELECT , para que me envie un response con los datos filtrado. Mi interrogante es tengo que mandar los datos con GET y poner los datos para filtrado en la URI (dominio.com/conductores?a=1&b=2) o mandarlos en el BODY del FETCH con un POST ?

Aqui mi RUTA
`conductorEnrutador.get('/conductores/:nombres/:apellidos/:transportista', conductorControlador.obtenerTodosComprimido)`

Aqui mi FETCH

````
        const config = {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(conditionalData)
        }

        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${apiDomain}/conductores`, config)
            if (response.status === 200) {
                const rows = await response.json()
                return rows
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error al obtener conductores ' + error.stack)
            return []
        }
    }
    ```
Nota: Obviar el error del BODY dentro del GET
      Tambien sé que cambiaria  la ruta si lo mandaria por POST o por GET (uri) , obviar tambien este error
````

Comment: Porque no construyes la URL con los valores? `${apiDomain}/conductores/${nombre}/${apellido}/${transportista}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una buena solución de como mandar parámetros por METODO GET, obviamente no en el `body`, sino a través de la `URL`, o lo que llaman QUERY STRING URL.
https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/256

```
// https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api
var url = new URL("https://geo.example.org/api"),
    params = {lat:35.696233, long:139.570431}
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
fetch(url).then(...)
```